My touchpad right click is not working on 22.04.4 LTS
I installed Gnome Tweaks some days ago. Then, in Gnome Tweaks, at the Keyboard and Touchpad menu, I select Fingers as the Mouse Click Emulation. Then I couldn't change my wallpaper. Then I disabled the Mouse Click Emulation. But my touchpad's right click is not working, only the two fingers emulation is working.
It's not like my wallpaper is not changing. It's got changed in the application menu, but it's not showing in my home screen. And also I couldn't right click in my home display, though the two fingers emulation is working on the other areas like clicking in the dock or on a terminal.
What should I do?
